# vsto reading file fails on item send

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

In my Outlook 2013-2016 addin I working with attachment. Attachments loads via property `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102` on item send and on item viewing.

```
byte[] attachmentData = attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102");
```

On item viewing attachments load successfully and I can work with it but on item sending I get exception `The property http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102 is unknown or cannot be found`. I know that it exception threw with large files but I load small .txt file and get exception anyway. Also it problem is revealed only with x64 Outlook (I tested on Outlook 2013 x86, Outlook 2016 x86 and Outlook 2016 x64). 
Is there an alternative way to load attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Large" files means anything over 32 kB. Make sure you save the message (MailItem.Save) first and check the attachment type - PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN is only for the olByRef attachments.

Comment: Yes, problem was with MailItem.Save, but why it not required on x86 Outlook?